# synchronous and statistical time division multiplexing

Tags: networking, router, multiplexing

### Wiki Definitions:

**Statistical multiplexing** is a type of communication link sharing, very similar to dynamic bandwidth allocation (DBA). In statistical multiplexing, a communication channel is divided into an arbitrary number of variable bit-rate digital channels or data streams. The link sharing is adapted to the instantaneous traffic demands of the data streams that are transferred over each channel. This is an alternative to creating a fixed sharing of a link, such as in general time division multiplexing (TDM) and frequency division multiplexing (FDM). When performed correctly, statistical multiplexing can provide a link utilization improvement, called the statistical multiplexing gain.

**Time-division multiplexing** (TDM) is a type of digital (or rarely analog) multiplexing in which two or more bit streams or signals are transferred apparently simultaneously as sub-channels in one communication channel, but are physically taking turns on the channel. The time domain is divided into several recurrent timeslots of fixed length, one for each sub-channel. A sample byte or data block of sub-channel 1 is transmitted during timeslot 1, sub-channel 2 during timeslot 2, etc. One TDM frame consists of one timeslot per sub-channel plus a synchronization channel and sometimes error correction channel before the synchronization. After the last sub-channel, error correction, and synchronization, the cycle starts all over again with a new frame, starting with the second sample, byte or data block from sub-channel 1, etc.

### Question:

What is the *english* or dumbed down difference between synchronous and statistical time division multiplexing?

Comment: I could try and interpret 1) its a freeforall, get what you can as fast as you can, colliding with everything else doing the same thing, if there is no traffic you get everything, the more actual data traffic the slower you get yours.  2) no mater how much traffic there is everyone gets similar time slices at it, it doesnt matter how big or fast your car is, they are allowing only 1 car per lane to go through at a time, and you will get yours, the same way as everyone else. although there could be many lanes that is happening on.